# jekyll and github - how to update the blog post?

Tags: github, jekyll

Good day.

Could you help me with a little problem I am experiencing.

I have a jekyll blog on the github. The problem is after I updated my old post, committed and pushed it, the blog post doesn't show any changes, but I see that the commit has been pushed successfully.

If I run jekyll --server locally, it shows updated blog post and it doesn't report any errors.
I have no jekyll plugins installed.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding? Thanks a lot.

---

Added by [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz):

I'm facing exactly same problem. My I pushed added one markdown post and few css, and modified layouts and includes, then I pushed them to github. It is done successfully. My github is showing all the changes in the repository, but the github blog (i.e the generated html posts out of markdown) are still same. No change to them at all. It is showing some posts which doesn't even exist in the repository. But when I do `jekyll --server` locally, then every update is being shown on my (local) blog hosted at `http://localhost:4000`.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you gotten a message from Github which states the pages built successfully? I've noticed, that if you push too often, Github seems to deprioritized you in the queue, and the pages don't get built right away. You may just have to wait until that happens.

Comment: no, I haven't got any message. I can't say I push too often (maybe 1-3 times per week).

Comment: Bummer, that would have made it easy :). Are you sure you modified the source and not the output of the build? Other that, I can't think of anything other than perhaps needing to purge your clientside cache with a shit refresh, perhaps, but that would be remote.

Comment: yes, I modified the post entry located in "_posts" folder (say, "2012-08-03-some-fancy-post.md").

Comment: hmm, after I modified, committed and pushed another file (this time it was ordinary css), github updated the website (as well as that blog post). hurrah!

Comment: Are you running any plugins?  I have had similar issues when using a plugin as a submodule.

Comment: no, I have no plugins installed. well, only pygments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your Jekyll site is not rendering properly after you push it to GitHub, it's useful to run Jekyll locally so you can see any parsing errors. In order to do this, you'll want to use the same version that we use.
GitHub's Pages servers currently use **Jekyll 0.11.0** with **Liquid 2.2.2**, and run it using this command:
`$ jekyll --pygments --safe`

[More info](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages)

Answer (score 2):

I'm now trying to solve the problems with my pygments highlighting (works locally, doesn't show on github at all, even though I'm receiving mails about succesful build). Findings so far:

- Make sure that youre repository' default branch is 'master' (go to your repository Admin page).
- Put your Jekyll source files in some other branch, and put the `_site` content to your master branch. There will be no `_config.yml`, no YAML front matter so github will render your stuff as is, and you would be building it locally on that other branch. This actually worked for me. It requires some manual labour when moving _site from that other branch to your master, but I'm fine with that - at least I do not have to rely on github build process which seems to be a bit buggy, plus, I can have whatever plugins I wish.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you generate your jekyll site locally for testing, always run `jekyll --no-auto --server`. This would display if there were any errors encountered during the generation of your site. Also, before generating your site delete `_site` directory and then run the command as described above.

Let me know if you see any errors as such. We can debug further